# In vim, how to split a word and flip the halves? FooBar => BarFoo

Tags: vim

I sometimes write a multi-word identifier in one order, then decide the other order makes more sense.  Sometimes there is a separator character, sometimes there is case boundary, and sometimes the separation is positional.  For example:

- `$foobar` becomes `$barfoo`
- `$FooBar` becomes `$BarFoo`
- `$foo_bar` becomes `$bar_foo`

How would I accomplish this in vim?  I want to put my cursor on the word, hit a key combo that cuts the first half, then appends it to the end of the current word.  Something like `cw`, but also yanking into the cut buffer and then appending to the current word (eg `ea`).

Nothing general and obvious comes to mind.  This is more a novelty question than one of daily practical use, but preference is given to shortest answer with fewest plugins.  *(Hmm, like code golf for vim.)*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this function, it swaps any word of the form `FooBar`, `foo_bar`, or `fooBar`:

```
function! SwapWord()
" Swap the word under the cursor, ex:
"  'foo_bar' --> 'bar_foo',
"  'FooBar'  --> 'BarFoo',
"  'fooBar'  --> 'barFoo' (keeps case style)
    let save_cursor = getcurpos()
    let word = expand("<cword>")
    let match_ = match(word, '_')
    if match_ != -1
        let repl = strpart(word, match_ + 1) . '_' . strpart(word, 0, match_)
    else
        let matchU = match(word, '\u', 1)
        if matchU != -1
            let was_lower = (match(word, '^\l') != -1)
            if was_lower
                let word = substitute(word, '^.', '\U\0', '')
            endif
            let repl = strpart(word, matchU) . strpart(word, 0, matchU)
            if was_lower
                let repl = substitute(repl, '^.', '\L\0', '')
            endif
        else
            return
        endif
    endif

    silent exe "normal ciw\<c-r>=repl\<cr>"
    call setpos('.', save_cursor)
endf
```

Mapping example:

```
noremap <silent> gs :call SwapWord()<cr>
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you talking about a single instance, globally across a file, or generically?

I would tend to just do a global search and replace, e.g.:

:1,$:s/$foobar/$barfoo/g

(for all lines, change $foobar to $barfoo, every instance on each line)

EDIT (single occurrence with cursor on the 'f'):

1. 3xep
2. 3xep  (had some ~ in there before the re-edit of the question)
3. 4xea_[ESC]px

Best I got for now. :)

Comment: Single instance.  See the OP edit.  For full file replace, I'd definitely use  `%s/$foobar/$barfoo`.

Comment: Ah, simple. Thanks!  This is the cut forward, paste to end approach.  The down-side is having to count forward.  For example, if the target word is `SubmissionAbstract`, I have to think pretty hard to count. :)

Answer (score 1):

`nnoremap <Leader>s dwbP`

Using Leader, s should now work.

```
dw : cut until the end of the word from cursor position
b : move cursor at the beginning of the word
P : paste the previously cut part at the front
```

It won't work for you last example though, you have to add another mapping to deal with _ .

(If you don't know what Leader is, see `:help mapleader`)

Comment: Cut from end and paste to front approach. Didn't even think of that, thanks!  This is elegant, I just wish it handled pivoting about the `_` gracefully.